# How to properly Use a dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dll and with a custom control in wpf and it is related to some other projects and folders. so if I want to use the dll into another project, what all file need to use/Copy , and what should be the place I need to keep the resource folder of the dll. If it is in bin folder how should be the physical arrangement

Comment: Do you want to reference the resource from within your WPF app or do you want to be able to modify the resource with external tools once the app is deployed?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If You want this dll should be shared accross multiple projects then all this dll into GAC.